# SQL Server SMO Method "Discover()"

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I think I just found the coolest thing every with SQL Server SMO and PowerShell. I was asked to get a script together to find the owner of every object in an instance of SQL Server. I found a script on Technet/MSDN SQL Server library but thought it would be a lot easier to get it with PowerShell and be able to hit all the instances on the network at once.

Well in playing around I came across this method within the Database class: [Discover()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.sqlsmoobject.discover)

So if you use this code:

```
#Load SMO 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo') | Out-Null
$srv = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' "your instance name"

$db = $srv.Databases

$db.Discover()
```

When you run that last line you are going to see your console start scrolling text like it is on drugs, if you connect to an instance with a lot of databases on it.

Well I went to do  `$db | gm`  and it pretty much shows you every TypeName available within SMO objects.

Now my question. I can execute `$db.Discover() | Select Name, Owner` and it will start spitting out everything with a name and an owner value.

How could I also get the object type of the object being returned (like if it is a trigger, schema, table, etc)? I can't seem to figure that out so far.

**EDIT**

So far I find that it seems to only "discovery" things on the database level. Apparently somewhere in my console cache I had set  `$db` to something like `$db = ($srv.Databases).Item("aDatabase")`, cause this is the only way you can call the method. Still looking for a way to pull out Object Name, type, and Owner though.

Comment: What other modules are you running? My profile is pretty bare. When I ran your code, I got a message saying that Smo.DatabaseCollection doesn't contain a method named Discover.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
$db.Discover() | select @{Name="Type";Expression={$_.GetType().Name}};
```

Comment: I figured it would have to be some type of expression. As is works but it is returning the TypeName of ScriptNameOjbectBase or SqlSmoOjbect; so I dropped the BaseType in the expression and it at least returns a more readable typename like "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.StoredProcedure".

Comment: So since everything does not have an owner, since Discover() also returns indexes, users, statistics I just need to figure out how to filter it down to only ownable objects.

Comment: Instead of the `BaseType` property, I'd suggest using the `Name` property.  It's a bit more readable: `$_.GetType().Name`.

Comment: What is the best way to filter out those objects that don't show an owner? I tried adding <code>? {$_.Owner -ne $NULL}</code> but it does not work or return what it should.

Comment: @ShawnMelton If you want to get all tables, for example, pipe your `Select-Object` cmdlet to this: `Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "Table"}`.  Make sense?

Comment: yep, breaking out the objects will make for a better report.

Comment: @ShawnMelton Sorry, I didn't really answer your question.  To get all objects that have an owner, pipe your `Select-Object` to this: `Where-Object {$_.Owner -ne $null}`

Comment: @ShawnMelton: Whoops... thought that that was returning the full type. Changed to reflect Shark's suggestion.

Comment: @Shark I tried the filter by Owner but it skews the results and it not returning everything that shows on owner without the filter. Don't know if it my environment doing that or not.

Comment: Ok never mind, now it does; must have fudged a character or something.

Comment: @ShawnMelton Don't know if I'm understanding your comment, but you're saying that it is filtering out objects where the Owner is in fact not null??

Comment: @ShawnMelton Ok, good.  Glad to see it's working. :)